# Função PHP chama Alerta Javascript mas não espera resposta

Tags: php, javascript, funções, sweetalert2

Olá.
Estou fazendo uma função em PHP em dentro de um if chamo uma função Javascript para exibir um alerto com o SweetAlert2.

O problema é que a função não está aguardando a resposta (clique em Ok) para dar continuidade na execução. Neste caso eu quero exibir a mensagem e quando o usuário clicar em Ok ele vai ser redirecionado para a URL usando o parametro que passo dentro da função.

```
Código PHP
```

```
function Atualizacao() {
  $Titulo =  $_REQUEST['f_titulo'];
  $Descricao = $_REQUEST['f_desc'];
  $Valor = $_REQUEST['f_valor'];
  $cod = $_GET['cod'];

if ($GLOBALS['$conexao']->connect_error) {
    die("Falha de Conexão: " . $GLOBALS['$conn']->connect_error);
  }
  
  $sql = "UPDATE produtos set titulo = '$Titulo', descricao = '$Descricao', valor = '$Valor', WHERE cod_produto = $cod";


  if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS['$conexao'], $sql)) {

    echo "<script>Alterado('produto')";
      
  } else {

    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['$conexao']);
  } 
  
  mysqli_close($GLOBALS['$conexao']);

}

}
```

```
Código Javascript
```

```
function AlteradoSucesso(tipo)
    {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Feito!",
        text: "Registro alterado com sucesso",
        icon: 'success',
        showConfirmButton: true
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            window.location = "home.php?tipo=" + tipo
          } 
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

acho que está faltando fechar a tag script no seu `if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS['$conexao'], $sql)) { echo "<script>AlteradoSucesso('produto');</script>";` e o nome da função está errado também.

Uma observação no teste que fiz a função precisou estar antes do código.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.4/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
<?php
echo 'teste';
?>
<script>
function AlteradoSucesso()
    {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Feito!",
        text: "Registro alterado com sucesso",
        icon: 'success',
        showConfirmButton: true
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            window.location = "home.php?tipo=" + tipo
          } 
      })
    }
</script>
<?php echo "<script>AlteradoSucesso();</script>"; ?>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não entendi o -1 na resposta, se jogar em um editor e rodar vai ver que ele executa e faz o que se espera, aparece o alerta e depois de clicar em ok ele vai pra outra pagina.